# The confused and problem about xml file format

Tags: xml, format

I write a xml like

```
<app>
   <html_code>
       <div id="id-5" class="portlet last">
            <div class="portlet-header">Weather</div>
            <div class="portlet-content">
            </div>
      </div>
   </html_code>
</app>
```

I use the "editix-xmleditor" to check or validate the xml file it's says correct

But when I insert a `<iframe></iframe>`tags and its infomation:

```
<app>
   <html_code>
       <div id="id-5" class="portlet last">
            <div class="portlet-header">Weather</div>
            <div class="portlet-content">
                <iframe src="http://www.thinkpage.cn/weather/weather.aspx?uid=&c=CHXX0008&l=zh-CHS&p=CMA&a=1&u=C&s=1&m=1&x=1&d=3&fc=&bgc=&bc=&ti=1&in=1&li=2&ct=iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="208" height="260" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
            </div>
      </div>
   </html_code>
</app>
```

then I check it again ,it tell me 
**"The reference to entity "c" must end with the ';' delimiter."**.

Also I use jquery $.ajax can't read the xml,it execute the error function  directly.

So how can I keep the `<iframe>` in original position,at the same time make the xml file correct?

What's the wrong with the iframe exactly?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to encode your ampersands as HTML entities; you can't simply write `&` as that signals the start of an entity, and thus you have to represent `&` characters as `&amp;`.

Comment: Drat, beat me by 1 measly second :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the URL. To have an ampersand (&) in a URL, it must be encoded as the entity `&amp;`